# How to open a new fragment to fragmentA in a fragmentActivity that include two fragme Layout

Tags: android, fragment

I have a question about Fragmet...
A FragmentAcitivty that include two fragmnets ,like this

```
FragmentActivity
+--------------------------------+
| ViewPager-FragmentA            |
| [Button]                       |
+--------------------------------+
| fragmentB                      |
+--------------------------------+
```

There a button in the fragment A , I wanna click the button that can open a new fragmentC , just replace the fragmentA block , and keep fragmentB block , keep in the FragmentActivity.

```
FragmentActivity
+--------------------------------+
| fragmentC                      |
|                                |
+--------------------------------+
| fragmentB                      |
+--------------------------------+
```

I have try using fragmentTransaction.add(..) then .commit() ,like this

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
UiSetupFragment uiSetupFragment = new UiSetupFragment();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.main_fragment_group, uiSetupFragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

But it will replace all of the FragmentActivity,like this

```
FragmentActivity
+--------------------------------+
| fragmentC                      |
|                                |
+--------------------------------+
```

I want ask how to just replace the fragmentA , not all the FragmentActivity
Sorry for my bad english,Thanks for your help

this is my xml file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_tile"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_fragment_group"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/botton_menu_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.ui.MenuFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Update :

I think because there are three fragment in one LinearyLayout , so while FragmentC be added in the LinearLayout , the fragmentB can not be visible (no space to display) , so I change my xml like this :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_tile"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_fragment_group"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
    </FrameLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/botton_menu_fragment"
        android:name="com.example.ui.MenuFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
ft.replace(R.id.details, new NewFragmentToReplace, "NewFragmentTag"); 
ft.commit();  use this

Comment: Please post your FragmentActivity layout.xml.

Comment: Did your fragmentC take up all the space of the screen ?

Comment: @Leog  , yes , When I use fragmentTransaction.add(...) , fragmentTransaction.commit(),  Then it take up all then screen , but I want   keep the fragmentB in visible

Comment: Set a dp value to the layout_height of FrameLayout main_fragment_group should solve your problem.

Comment: ok~~Thank you @Leog , I thnik I have knew how to solve it  :)